# need to create certificate with open SSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have two servers and on server A I have the open SSL install and on server B, I don't have the open SSL install now if I create a key pair and generate a CSR from server A for server B and get it signed by my root authority and place it on my server B now how this will work when the private key is still present on my server A as I have done everything on server A and just place the signed certificate on server B. how server B will decrypt the traffic when it didn't have the private key.

OpenSSL genrsa -out marvels.gq.key 4096
 openssl req -new -key marvels.gq.key -out marvels.gq.csr

Comment: A certificate can not be used if the private key is not installed alongside it. Said differently: if you copy your certificate elsewhere to be used, then you need to copy (or move) your private key as well. Also your question not being about programming is offtopic here, see instead [su] probably.

Comment: PS: and your question has nothing to do specifically with TLS1.2