# open SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

0

I have two servers and on server A I have the open SSL install and on server B, I don't have the open SSL install now if I create a key pair and generate a CSR from server A for server B and get it signed by my root authority and place it on my server B now how this will work when the private key is still present on my server A as I have done everything on server A and just place the signed certificate on server B. how server B will decrypt the traffic when it didn't have the private key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [need to create certificate with open SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494429/need-to-create-certificate-with-open-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

You are right to question - Server B will *NOT* be able to function securely without access to a copy of the private key generated for the Certificate.  Both portions are required for any device to create an encrypted session.